# datetime converstion from yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s to yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00Z

Tags: php, datetime

How can i convert a datetime in the format `yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s` to `yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00Z (UTC)`. As my default timezone is not in UTC but i can set that for this conversion. for [Amazon CloudSearch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/faqs/) supporting format.

Comment: And what you have tried. I think you've got multiple duplicate questions related to it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php/2167925#2167925

Comment: I want to convert the date available in mysql database to Amazon CloudSearch supporting format.

Comment: Mark it is not giving the format Amazon accept.

Uchiha Can you get me one link?

Comment: What's so difficult about `$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateString);
$newDateString = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d\T00:00:00\Z (\U\T\C)');`

Answer (score 2):

Simply try using `gmdate` function as

```
$timestamp = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z P');
echo $timestamp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

$old_format = "2015-06-07 11:05:10";

$new_format = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", strtotime($old_format));

echo $new_format;